# sending remote data to Videojet Machine using Enhanced Serial Interface(ESI)

Tags: networking, tcpclient

I have a  Videojet Machine  which is working with ESI(Enhanced Serial Interface) Commands , i cam connecting through Port 3000 , sending a Command like @12345   for test sending data but I am getting no response at all from the machine I am using Hercules Hyper Terminal
[Hercules Term used to send ESI Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdwC0.png)

the PDF for the ESI language
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y2sawtv17xjqe4nREK0L25frmW8sJUgO/view?usp=share_link

thanks in advance

I try connecting to the Machine using Hercules Hyper term

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.